# Image of cell does not change in didDeselectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I try to change status of image in the cell of the `UICollectionView` object...

this is a part of my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell *aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];    

[aCell.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.imageArray[indexPath.item]]];
if (aCell.selected) {

    aCell.myImage.layer.borderWidth =  1.0;
    aCell.myImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            aCell.mySelect.hidden = NO;

} else {

    aCell.myImage.layer.borderWidth =  0.0;
    aCell.myImage.layer.borderColor = nil;
            aCell.mySelect.hidden = YES;
}

return aCell;

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSLog(@"Select");
cell *selectedCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (selectedCell.selected) {

    [selectedCell.mySelect setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"]];
    selectedCell.myImage.layer.borderWidth =  1.0;
    selectedCell.myImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    selectedCell.mySelect.hidden = NO;

} else {
    [selectedCell.mySelect setImage:nil];
    selectedCell.myImage.layer.borderWidth =  0.0;
    selectedCell.myImage.layer.borderColor = nil;
    selectedCell.mySelect.hidden = YES;    }

}
```

when i tap any cell, the value select changes, but view object does not refresh.

Comment: `[self.collectionView reload];` added?

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh your row selected with this methos from your didSelectItemAtindexPath method

`- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are dequeue Cell, when cell is selected .
write following code

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
     NSLog(@"Select");
     cell *selectedCell= (cell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     [selectedCell.mySelect setImage:(selectedCell.selected) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"]: nil];
     [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPath];
 }
```

Comment: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'cell *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'  cell - my class, child of uicollectionviewcell

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override `selected/highlighted` property in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass for this task instead of using reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell *selectedCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This code will create a NEW cell! Your viewController is not contain this cell!

You should use correct method for getting selected cell:

```
[yourContentView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```